# Why images loaded by Glide get downsampled to low resolution in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm switching from `Picasso` to `Glide` in my app. I have a `RecyclerView`, each of whose items is a `CustomView`. This `CustomView` adds `TextView` or `ImageView` dynamically based on different data sources.

A `FillWidthImageView` is used to display these images, it fill the screen width automatically. When I use `Picasso`, it works well. However, when I use `Glide` to load images, the image displayed in the `FillWidthImageView` looks like a mosaic with extremely low resolution, because it's heavily downsampled.

And if I use a normal `ImageView` instead, size of loaded image is the same as the placeholder, and images still look like a mosaic. If there is no placeholder, the images look tiny on the screen. And if I display the images in an empty `Activity`, they will be loaded with full resolution and correct size.

---

Code of adding `ImageView` in my `CustomView`(extends `LinearLayout`), called in `RecyclerView.onCreateViewHolder()`

```
public void addImageView() {
    ImageView imageView = new FillWidthImageView(getContext());
    imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    addView(imageView);
}
```

Code of `FillWidthImageView`

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
    if (drawable != null) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int diw = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        if (diw > 0) {
            int height = width * drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / diw;
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    } else
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Code of loading images, called in `RecyclerView.onBindItemViewHolder()`

```
Glide.with(getContext()).load(url).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Hitesh Kr Sahu, but I have solved of the bug by myself. It's because the Glide didn't get the right dimensions of my `CustomView` wrapper. I solved this bug by applying the dimensions by calling `.override(int,int)` and `.fitCenter()`. I passed the width and height of screen to it, so it will be scaled fitting the screen size.

Comment: Working solution. Save my night! Thankssss!

Answer (score 1):

Image loaded by Glide has the worse quality compared to Picasso because Glide's default Bitmap Format is set to RGB_565 & it consumed just 50% memory footprint compared to ARGB_8888.

That make Glide faster than Picasso as you can see in this *[**video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4QCnptbzUw)*.

Good news is you can switch Bitmap Format to ARGB_8888 by creating a new class which extended from GlideModule like this :-

```
public class GlideConfiguration implements GlideModule {

    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        // Apply options to the builder here.
        builder.setDecodeFormat(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
        // register ModelLoaders here.
    }
}
```

and adding metadata field in manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.inthecheesefactory.lab.glidepicasso.GlideConfiguration"
            android:value="GlideModule"/>
```

You can read more about it here glide Configuration page of Glide's wiki and as you have switched from Picasso you will find [**this**](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) an interesting read

Comment: It is necessary to call this GlideConfiguration from anywhere or it's just okay declaring it? Because it is not working for me.